# Creating a table in python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a document named `Payments.txt` and I have appended it to `myList`. Each line of `Payments.txt` has its own list within `myList`. The code has striped and split each line of `Payments.txt`. `details` searches through `myList` and picks up the lists that contain the status of "A" and those who haven't paid all the money that they are meant to pay. This is where the table comes in. This is my code:(I am using python 3.5)

```
myList = []
Status = "A"
myFile = open("Payments.txt")
record = myFile.readlines()
for line in record:
    myList.append(line.strip().split(','))
myFile.close()
for z in record:
    details = [x for x in myList if len(x) == 5 and x[3] == Status and x[2]>x[4]]
    if details:
        print(details)
        break
```

I have attempted to use the `from tabulate import tabulate` function, but it hasn't worked for me. It returned with the error message:

```
ImportError: No module named 'tabulate'
```

How can I correct this error? It is the importing that is the error I believe.

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? Is it that importing it raises an error?

As a workaround you could potentially use pprint to print your table.

Comment: Yes, it is the importing that is the error. I don't want to use print as it is more difficult to use(printing the structure of the table).

Comment: It seems like this is really two questions: a block of code that really needs to be fixed to be an [mcve] and, judging by the answer and your response, it sounds like you also don't know how to install python packages, hence the import error; this is probably something you need to fix by reading e.g. the link provided.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a CSV file (comma separated) you can easily see a table using the `pandas` library.

```
pip install pandas
```

Now for the magic:

```
import pandas as pd
table = pd.read_csv('filename.txt')
table

# output should be the entire table
# if you don't want to see the whole table use:

table.head()
# or

table.tail()
```

Now you have a DataFrame object which you can query and do all kinds of fun stuff with.

Comment: Where do you put the `pip install pandas`?

Comment: It depends on your system. If you're using windows... I'm not sure but try the console. It should be in the start menu. If you're on a mac, use the terminal. If you're on linux (my system of choice and hence why I'm not so familiar with the exact names in Win/Mac) use the terminal (ctrl+alt+t).

Comment: More info here: http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing/

Comment: The more info link is broken. Here is the [installing packages](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) page.